# Prevent Angular JS Directive from Firing Twice when moving element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Every time the element is appended, it fires the directive again. I simply want to move **elem** into the **icr-main-modal-placement** element.

```
.directive('icrMainModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/icr-main-modal.html',
    scope: {
      state: '=icrVState'
    },
    transclude: true,
    compile: function(elem, attrs) {

      angular.element('icr-main-modal-placement').append(elem); // because of this, the directive is fired again. I just want to move elem into 'icr-main-modal-placement'

      return function(scope, elem) {

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          return elem.remove();
        });

      };

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you show your html on how you are using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to make this directive for Attribute instead of Element and remove the attribute in the compile/link method?

```
.directive('icrMainModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'views/icr-main-modal.html',
    scope: {
      state: '=icrMainModal'
    },
    transclude: true,
    compile: function(elem, attrs) {
      elem.removeAttr('icr-main-modal');
      angular.element('icr-main-modal-placement').append(elem); 

      return function(scope, elem) {

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          return elem.remove();
        });

      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Yeah! That's what I thought of too, it's a bummer that there seems to only be what seems like a workaround, rather than a solution (perhaps though, this is not a common problem). But this works for me, thank you for looking into it!